# How to get Count of Joined Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is this SQL Statement

```
    SELECT t1.Name
    ,Count(t2.SubID) Totals -- I don't know how to do it.
    FROM Table t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.SubID
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you give a sample please... to be sure what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Guessing*... change the JOIN and add GROUP BY

```
SELECT t1.Name
,Count(t2.SubID) AS Totals
FROM Table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.SubID 
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` allows you to find count zero rows per `t1.Name`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Name, Count(t2.SubID) Totals
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.SubID 
GROUP BY t1.Name
```